# Left join mysql which is loading indefinitely

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

This code is loading indefinitely:

```
$answer_articles = $bdd->prepare(
 "SELECT * 
  FROM todo
  LEFT JOIN links_task_text
  ON links_task_text.links_task_text_id_task = todo.ID
  WHERE todo.site = ?");
$answer_articles->execute(array('xxx'));
exit();
```

This code is of course working:

```
$answer_articles = $bdd->prepare(
 "SELECT * 
  FROM todo
  WHERE site = ?");
$answer_articles->execute(array('xxx'));
exit();

//working and no loading delays
```

And this code is working as well:

```
$answer_articles = $bdd->prepare(
 "SELECT * FROM todo
  INNER JOIN links_task_text
  ON links_task_text.links_task_text_id_task = todo.ID
  WHERE todo.site = ?");
$answer_articles->execute(array('xxx'));
exit();

//works but it's not what I need
```

`links_task_text.links_task_text_id_task` and `todo.ID` are INT.

I don't understand why the left join isn't working. Some ideas?

Comment: Did you try to run your SQL code without PHP ? And please post your table structure with data for example

Comment: You should have index. Please post EXPLAIN, and your tables structure

Answer (score 1):

Does column links_task_text_id_task have an index on it?

If not it could be that the query is running a full table scan on links_task_text that is taking a long time.

Comment: Thanks, it works ! I didn't have index.
I'm going to learn about this.